# How to add footer in dropdown in UWP combobox

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, uwp, combobox, uwp-xaml

I am developing an UWP application. I want a footer to be displayed where combobox items get displayed. How to achieve it in UWP. Help me to implement this.

[Want to achieve like this snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azGpM.png)

**Note :**
Here am using Microsoft Combobox

Answer (score 0):

You just need to customize the ComboBox default style and put a TextBlock control in the dropdown popup.

See [Use tools to work with styles easily](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/xaml-styles#use-tools-to-work-with-styles-easily) to edit a copy ComboBox style and find the Popup control. Put the TextBlock like the following:

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle1" TargetType="ComboBox">
......

<Popup x:Name="Popup">                      
<ScrollViewer>
      <RelativePanel>
            <Border  x:Name="PopupBorder" BackgroundSizing="OuterBorderEdge" Background="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropDownBackground}" BorderThickness="0 0 0 2" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropDownBorderBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,-1,0,-1" Padding="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropdownBorderPadding}">
                   <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange}" Foreground="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropDownForeground}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" MinWidth="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownContentMinWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" VerticalSnapPointsType="OptionalSingle" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalSnapPointsAlignment="Near" ZoomMode="Disabled">
                        <ItemsPresenter Margin="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropdownContentMargin}" />
                   </ScrollViewer>
            </Border>
            <TextBlock Text="Manage Styles" RelativePanel.Below="PopupBorder"></TextBlock>
      </RelativePanel>
</ScrollViewer>
</Popup>
```